# Coq nat type check on match

Tags: types, coq

```
Theorem nzgtz : ~ 0 > 0.
Proof.
unfold not.
unfold gt.
unfold lt.
intros H.
inversion H.
Qed.

Print nzgtz.

Definition pred1 (n : nat) : n > 0 -> nat :=
  match n with
 | O => fun pf => match (nzgtz pf) with end
 | S n' => fun _ => n'
 end.
```

I am confused about how the first branch with the `O` returns a function with type `(0 > 0) -> nat`. The question is: how is `match False with end` a `nat`? It seems that no value is returned?! What does that expression mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert. But from a functional point of view, the return value of `pred1` is a **function returning** `nat`, and **not** a `nat`. For any input `n`, the result function turns a proof `pf` of `n > 0` into a `nat`.

A function does not need to (or cannot) return any value on a non-existing parameter. In the extreme case, when the domain of the function is empty, the codomain is (or can be viewed as) empty as well.

That's why when the `pf` is in `False` (which is an empty type), the function cannot return any specific `nat` value, and it has to return nothing.

Syntactically, if you compare a simplified version of the function with one from `nat` to `nat`:

```
Definition p : False -> nat :=
 fun pf => match pf with end.

Definition p1 : nat -> nat :=
 fun pf => match pf with 
   | 0 => 0
   | S p => p
end.
```

the proof `pf` for `False` in `p` has no constructors (0 branches) to `match with`, as compared to the two branches/constructors in `p1`.

For a similar reason, you can use a proof of `False` to (*vacuously*) prove anything.

Comment: I understand this intuition, but I'd like to be really rigorous. How exactly is it that the first branch is of type (n > 0) -> nat? nat is defined in Coq as being constructed from a zero (O) and its successors (S(0), S(1), etc). There is no "empty" quantity associated with nat. Although (0 > 0) should evaluate to False, shouldn't a nat still be returned from the function?

Comment: @pyrrhic I think you cannot return any `nat` meaningfully. If you have a function `f: Empty -> nat`, what should be the image/codomain of the function? Nothing can be in the image or returned because there is nothing to map from in the domain. `False` is such an empty type with no inhabitant in it.

Answer (score 2):

The `match X with end` is meant to rule out impossible cases. Indeed, the typical way to read the zero branch of your `pred1` function would be as "this case is impossible".

Thus, an impossible case doesn't need a return value.

p.s: Note that I cannot envision a scenary where `pred1` would be useful.

Comment: Oh, `pred1` is very useful in teaching :). It strongly resembles the `pred_strong1` function from [cpdt](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.Subset.html), used as an introductory example to teach dependent types programming and specifically subset types.

Comment: @AntonTrunov that's the kind of reference I was looking for!! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AntonTrunov I see! However I am not a fan at all of that chapter, neither of that particular subtype approach; naive application of the pattern leads to huge proof irrelevance issues, IMHO it is better to start with a true subtype library from the beginning, even if the learning curve is higher.

Comment: Is there an example of such 'true subtype library'? It would be very interesting to look at a concrete example to fully comprehend what you mean.

Comment: By "true" I meant complete. I think many people have rolled their own, I use this one: http://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.eqtype.html thou the full power of it only comes later (see tuple.v). What I meant is, when does `pred pf1 n1 = pred pf2 n2` holds?

Comment: @ejgallego Stumbled upon your last comment by chance :) It's easy to prove that this modified `pred` behaves much better than the standard one: `Lemma pred_eq n1 n2 pf1 pf2 :
  (pred n1 pf1 = pred n2 pf2) <-> n1 = n2.`

Comment: Well, I think that "much better" here is not well defined. In fact, pred is not the best example, take subtraction `n - m`, a dependently typed version won't behave better at all in practice, in particular for rewriting.